# Busqueda regex que contenga la palabra

Tags: regex

Buenas soy nuevo en las expresiones regulares.
Tengo este regex que lo que hace buscar en una cadena de texto los que coincida con las dos palabras completas exactas.

Pero lo que necesitaría es que busque que contenga la palabra de búsqueda.
No consigo que funcione como necesitaría.

Os dejo el regex

`^(?=.*\btest\b)(?=.*\bjavascript\b)`

Gracias

Comment: y qué has intentado?

Comment: Estás buscando solo las palabras `test` y `javascript`? Podrías intentar poniendo solo las palabras que necesitas `(test|javaScript)/gi`, `g` hace una búsqueda general, y la `i` hace la búsqueda ya sea si es mayuscula o minúscula

Answer (score -3):

```
porque no haces algo mas facil

string palabra ="busqueda";

string palabrabuscada ="";

if(palabrabuscada=!palabra){
 console.log("la palabra buscada no existe");
else{
 console.log("exito");
}

la expresion regular solo te inpedira ingresar una cadena tal cual en el input.
```